# Beginner JavaScript Pattern

Tags: javascript, object, design-patterns

I'm recently started studying objects, closures, scopes and the such. I'm trying to implement my own code using these techniques but am running into issues.

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;

    return {
        ageUp: function ageUp() {
            this.age++;
        },
        printInfo: function printInfo() {
            console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
        },
        changeName: function changeName(newName) {
            this.name = newName;
        }
    }
}


var jeff = new Person('jeff', 28);
jeff.printInfo();
```

Oddly, this returns `undefined is undefined years old`. Does the `printInfo` property not have `this.name` in its scope because the returned object has no recollection of the function?

Also oddly enough, if I change all the instances of `this.name` and `this.age` to regular private variables (such as `var personName = name;`), somehow the returned object will operate properly and I can use the `ageUp` and `printInfo` as expected.

Am I combining two design patterns that I shouldn't be? What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

```
return { ...
```

You are creating a new object, separate from the object that the `new` keyword previously created (the one you assigned two properties to). You might notice that `jeff instanceof Person` is false and `jeff.constructor === Object`.

See this example:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;

    return {
        theObjectThatNewCreated: this
    }
}

var jeff = new Person('jeff', 28);
console.log( JSON.stringify( jeff ) );
// {"theObjectThatNewCreated":{"name":"jeff","age":28}}
console.log( jeff.constructor );
// Object
console.log( jeff.theObjectThatNewCreated.constructor );
// Person
```

You could fix it by assigning the name and age properties to the object you return instead of to `this`:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    return {
        name: name,
        age: age,
        ageUp: function ageUp() {
            this.age++;
        },
        printInfo: function printInfo() {
            console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
        },
        changeName: function changeName(newName) {
            this.name = newName;
        }
    }
}


var jeff = new Person('jeff', 28);
jeff.printInfo();
```

But then Person isn't really a constructor, it is just an object factory and there is no point calling it with `new`. The objects it returns are not instances of Person, they are plain old Objects. There is a better way.

> Am I combining two design patterns that I shouldn't be? What would be the best way to go about this?

I would say you are combining the revealing module pattern with a normal JavaScript constructor.

Instead of returning a new object you can just use `this` all the way through, to assign those functions as properties of the Person object instead of a new object:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;

    this.ageUp = function ageUp() {
        this.age++;
    };

    this.printInfo = function printInfo() {
        console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
    };

    this.changeName = function changeName(newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    };
}


var jeff = new Person('jeff', 28);
jeff.printInfo();
```

But since those functions don't use any closed over variables from the constructor, they really should be added to the prototype of the constructor instead:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
}

Person.prototype.ageUp = function ageUp() {
    this.age++;
};

Person.prototype.printInfo = function printInfo() {
    console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
};

Person.prototype.changeName = function changeName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
};

var jeff = new Person('jeff', 28);
jeff.printInfo();
```

Comment: Good answer, Can you please clarify the sentence "those functions don't use any closed over variables from the constructor"?
Could not understand it...

Comment: @chenop I mean a variable declared with `var` inside the constructor, or a parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that you are combining two patterns. Firstly, under normal circumstances, a constructor wouldn't return anything. (There are exceptions which I won't delve into here).

You probably want to do something like this:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
}

Person.prototype.printInfo = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
};

// and so on. Now you can say

var jeff = new Person('jeff', 28);
jeff.printInfo(); // => jeff is 28 years old
```

I am assuming you want those methods on the prototype so they are shared (it's not mandatory however).

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a new object in your constructor. So, you would not receive an instance of `Person` when calling `new Person(...)` rather than a dump object which has your defined properties.

Try to define your methods object as the prototype of your constructor:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
}

Person.prototype = {
    ageUp: function ageUp() {
        this.age++;
    },
    printInfo: function printInfo() {
        console.log(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
    },
    changeName: function changeName(newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your properties `name` and `age` private, your could define your methods in the constructor. Simply assign methods to `this.`. For private properties, you don't have to assign the properties itself to your instance:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.ageUp = function ageUp() {
        age++;
    };

    this.printInfo = function printInfo() {
        console.log(name + " is " + age + " years old");
    };

    this.changeName = function changeName(newName) {
        name = newName;
    };
}
```

But I would prefer the first example. In the second, each new instance will create new methods. In the first example, all your instances refers to a single prototype object which should use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the surrounding return {} in your class and it should work.